# Difference between uncss and purifycss

Tags: npm, gruntjs, uncss

I'm already using [uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss) with grunt, but stumbled upon [purifycss](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss).

I can't seem to find comparisons anywhere.

Can anyone tell me the difference between the two to help me choose the right one?

Answer (score 9):

**UnCSS removes unused CSS from your stylesheets.**

**PurifyCSS does not modify the original CSS files.**

I use PurifyCSS and I full recommend.

I hope that simplify the things for you, everyone has a way to do the things. If I were you I would test both and see which one is more helpful for you.

**EDIT:**
PurifyCSS takes also care about JS-Files which could add CSS classes and IDs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more recent comparison, courtesy of another similar project, purgecss: https://www.purgecss.com/comparison.html

---

### Summary

#### PurifyCSS

- Works with any file type, not just HTML or JS
- Uses *extractors*, which takes the content of a file and extracts the list of CSS selectors used in it

#### UnCSS

- Effective at removing unused selectors from web apps due to HTML emulation and JS execution.

  - This has a performance cost.
- Most accurate tool if you don't use server-side rendering.
- No extractor for JS files, but developers can create extractors for specific frameworks and file types.

Comment: There are some errors in this summary. Extractors are part of Purgecss.

Comment: @Ffloriel can you elaborate please? The summary states that PurifyCSS uses extractors.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lack of precision.
Purifycss considers all files to be the same. They are not treated differently. When purifycss comes across a js file, it will look at the files and consider every word a potential css selector. It will do the same for a file  .html, .pug, .blade, etc...
With Purifycss, you can't change this behavior. You can consider that Purifycss has 1 extractor that can't be replaced or customized.